# Axis2 Implementation pattern for querying several servers

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Im doing a (School) project where a Client should query several Servers, the servers each run the same webservice (In Axis2 1.5.4).

I think the stub-generation approach would be stupid in this case, so are there any smart ways to exploit the fact that each server is equal? Ive read a bit about the ServiceClient which seems to be the way to go, but i just want to get that confirmed / de-confirmed from someone with a bit of experience in the field.

Regards Sune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could still use a [`Stub`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Stub.html) in this scenario. A [`Stub`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Stub.html) reference has a method called [`_getServiceClient()`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Stub.html#_getServiceClient%28%29) which gets you the associated [`ServiceClient`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html) object for that [`Stub`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Stub.html). From there, you can call [`getOptions()`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#getOptions%28%29) on that [`ServiceClient`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html) and set any number of parameters on that [`Options`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html) instance. The method you are looking for to set the endpoint is [`setTo(EndpointReference)`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/client/Options.html#setTo%28org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference%29). So putting that all together, here is the code:

```
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTo(new EndpointReference(endpoint));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, wasnt aware that was possible.